# PHP pspell can't find installed language

Tags: php, aspell

I would like to use pspell in english, hungarian and slovak languages. I've installed both `hu` and `sk` language packs with `apt-get install aspell-hu` and `apt-get install aspell-sk`. If I check the installed dictionaries in aspell, I can see it's ok:

```
/# aspell dicts
en
en-variant_0
...
en_US-wo_accents
hu
sk
sk-extended
sk_SK
sk_SK-extended
```

If I check a file with aspell in command line, it also works:

```
/# aspell --lang=hu check README.txt
```

But in PHP I've got the following error:

```
 pspell_new(): PSPELL couldn't open the dictionary. reason: No word lists can be found for the language "hu".
```

For english it just works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed and reinstalled the php pspell package solved the problem. So the solution was:

```
#apt-get remove php5-pspell

#apt-get install php5-pspell
```